# testcafe: "Error while loading extension HubsExtension" while accessing "Resource Group" tab in Azure portal

Tags: azure, testcafe

Issue: Seeing the following error while trying to click "Resource Groups" in Azure portal using testcafe and the page crashes. I have tried chrome, firefox and edge without any success. Even chrome incognito has same issue.

Error while loading extension HubsExtension: ErrorLogged

URL: https://portal.azure.com/#create/Microsoft.ResourceGroup

Detailed Error:

1:17:32 PM ShellWorkerImpl/Core/ExtensionManager 0 ExtensionManager: _errorData: undefined
_sourceErrorLevel: undefined
baseTypes: ["MsPortalFx.Errors.Error"]
code: undefined
data: {"extVersion":"9.401.1.19.401.0.16568301.220519-0046","timeThisExtensionFailed":612.0999999046326,"extensionTelemetry":[{"messageReceivedTimes":{},"uriUsed":"https://portal.azure.com/AzureHubs?bundlingKind=DefaultPartitioner&cacheability=3&clientOptimizations=true&configHash=u2nVAiiCAiFU&environmentjson=true&extensionName=HubsExtension&l=en&pageVersion=9.401.1.19.401.0.16568301.220519-0046&trustedAuthority=portal.azure.com","loadRequestedTime":308.59999990463257,"environmentFetchTime":333.7999999523163,"afdCorrelationHeader":"0gj2nygaaaabtk+g+nk/qrjw2whiikwqqu0pdrurhrta1mdgamzvinjm2mgityjyxyi00yzc2lwjmn2qtzju4m2y4odqxowy5","workerLoadRetryCount":0,"homepageSize":"18940","afdCacheHit":false}],"error":{"type":"ErrorLogged","error":{"message":"Error loading initial scripts.","error":{"message":"Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 'http://192.168.86.52:60523/!s/https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/Pm6cLXkhkVQ6.js' failed to load.","name":"NetworkError","stack":"Error: Failed to execute 'importScripts' on 'WorkerGlobalScope': The script at 'http://192.168.86.52:60523/!s/https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/Pm6cLXkhkVQ6.js' failed to load.\n    at importScripts (http://192.168.86.52:60523/worker-hammerhead.js:3:2255)\n    at blob:[http://192.168.86.52:60523/f229fd58-a6a4-47e3-ae0a-f7f6a9782008:2:2390\n](http://192.168.86.52:60523/f229fd58-a6a4-47e3-ae0a-f7f6a9782008:2:2390%5Cn)    at c (blob:http://192.168.86.52:60523/f229fd58-a6a4-47e3-ae0a-f7f6a9782008:2:1552)\n    at Object.a [as webWorkerInitialize] (blob:http://192.168.86.52:60523/f229fd58-a6a4-47e3-ae0a-f7f6a9782008:2:2351)\n    at blob:[http://192.168.86.52:60523/f229fd58-a6a4-47e3-ae0a-f7f6a9782008:2:3341"}},"timestamp":1030.5}}](http://192.168.86.52:60523/f229fd58-a6a4-47e3-ae0a-f7f6a9782008:2:3341%22%7D%7D,%22timestamp%22:1030.5%7D%7D)
errorData: undefined
errorLevel: 2
extension: fx
handled: undefined
innerErrors: []
message: Error while loading extension HubsExtension: ErrorLogged
name: Error
source: undefined
stack: Error: Error while loading extension HubsExtension: ErrorLogged
at new t (http://192.168.86.52:60523/E8ofx2QCO*vnyDCnZtq!s!utf-8/https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/Pm6cLXkhkVQ6.js:77:904)
at Object.Q.nextTick.v.requirejs.t.createError (http://192.168.86.52:60523/E8ofx2QCO*vnyDCnZtq!s!utf-8/https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/Pm6cLXkhkVQ6.js:73:7116)
at s (http://192.168.86.52:60523/E8ofx2QCO*vnyDCnZtq!s!utf-8/https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/Pm6cLXkhkVQ6.js:238:4263)
at Object.errorHandler (http://192.168.86.52:60523/E8ofx2QCO*vnyDCnZtq!s!utf-8/https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/Pm6cLXkhkVQ6.js:238:4923)
at y (http://192.168.86.52:60523/E8ofx2QCO*vnyDCnZtq!s!utf-8/https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/Pm6cLXkhkVQ6.js:235:6475)
at http://192.168.86.52:60523/E8ofx2QCO*vnyDCnZtq!s!utf-8/https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/Pm6cLXkhkVQ6.js:235:6534
at http://192.168.86.52:60523/E8ofx2QCO*vnyDCnZtq!s!utf-8/https://portal.azure.com/Content/Dynamic/Pm6cLXkhkVQ6.js:233:1548
timestamp: 612.1999999284744
type: MsPortalFx.Errors.Error

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the detailed information. I reproduced this issue and created a new bug report regarding it: [2768](https://github.com/DevExpress/testcafe-hammerhead/issues/2768). We will update it once we have any news.